# Android Studio: exclude gradle task from build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, task

I wrote a small task, which updates an Android library from the web. This should only be done on request. I know, that there is a '-x' option, but this seems to apply only on gradle itself. The task gets executed whenever I try to build my project with Android Studio. Is there a way to exclude specific task from being executed?

My gradle task look like:

```
task downloadSDK {
    print 'Downloading SDK...'

    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

    ant.get(
            src: 'http://example.com/SDK.zip',
            username:properties.getProperty('USERNAME', null),
            password:properties.getProperty('PASSWORD', null),
            dest:"${buildDir}/sdk.zip",
            verbose:true)

    println 'done'
}

task updateSDK(type: Copy) {
    print 'Copying SDK...'
    delete "src/main/java/"
    def zipFile = file("${buildDir}/sdk.zip")
    def outputDir = file("src/main/java")
    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outputDir
    println 'done'
}

updateSDK.dependsOn downloadSDK
```

I thought that I just have to add `<<` to my updateSDK, but it doesn't seem to work with the Copy task.

Comment: Show your task code. You're likely missing `doLast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the gradle spec more deeply, I found out, that Copy is actually not a task but rather a function. So, my gradle task has to look like:

```
task updateSDK << {
    print 'Copying SDK...'
    delete "src/main/java/"

    def zipFile = file("${buildDir}/sdk.zip")
    def outputDir = file("src/main/java")
    copy {
        from zipTree(zipFile)
        into outputDir
    }
    println 'done'
}
```

The difference is that I call the copy function inside a task so that doLast will work correctly.